# How to avoid TCPDF error suppressing system?

Tags: php, error-handling, tcpdf

TCPDF uses a lot the PHP @ operator to suppress error.
As my application use a custom error handler, it still get these "suppressed" errors.

How can I make it ignore @-suppressed errors?

I thought of finding out if the error comes from TCPDF using the backtrace but the error may come from a line not using @ operator.
Such a line looks like (l. 6882) for instance:

```
if (($imsize = @getimagesize($file)) === FALSE) {
```

I've asked Nicola Asuni (TCPDF creator) about this specific error and he said: "The code is working fine and the error has been suppressed on purpose".

I use PHP function set_error_handler to handle errors.

And the following: error_reporting(E_ALL); on PHP 5.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check for `error_reporting()` inside the error handler (you should read the **[PHP Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)**, it explains your concrete case there)

See the example (adapted from [**PHP DOCS**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php)):

```
function myErrorHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    if (!(error_reporting() & $errno)) {
        // This error code is not included in error_reporting or was called with @
        return;
    }

    throw new ErrorException($errstr, 0, $errno, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler('myErrorHandler');

@strpos();
```